# jQueryMobile's data-title not displayed in search results

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, seo, web-crawler

I have a multi-paged jQueryMobile site that uses the `data-title` attribute to update the page title on each individual page. This works fine in most modern browsers, but it is not reflected in the Google search results, as the crawler probably doesn't support jQueryMobile (or javascript for that matter).

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're updating the page using JavaScript which is generally **not** parsed by search engines. So if you want the titles to be reflected in the search results you have to set it on the server before sending out your HTML.

Comment: What do mean by setting it on the server?

Comment: Creating the content on the server before the page is sent to the browser/webcrawler